# acronym with inputenc changes between latin10 and utf8

Tags: packages, acronyms, input-encodings

[edited] finished OK MWE

This is `mwe.dtx`.

```
% \iffalse    (METACOMMENT)
%%
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
%% Document class `mwe' to use with LaTeX 2e.
%%
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
% \fi
%
% \CheckSum{419}
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
% ^^A \MakeShortVerb{\|}
% \section{Internals}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<class>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \iffalse (Don't show this in the doc).
%<*driver>
         \ProvidesFile{mwe.drv}
%</driver>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<class>\ProvidesClass{./mwe}
        [2012/05/24 v1.0
%<class>        A mwe class]
%    \end{macrocode}
% \iffalse (Omitted from the doc)
%<*driver>
]
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \subsection{Driver for this document}
%
% This program will extract the following driver from this file:
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
%\DisableCrossrefs % Say \DisableCrossrefs if index is ready
\RecordChanges
%\OnlyDescription % Comment out for implementation details
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{mwe.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{macro}{\my@op@n}
% \begin{macro}{\my@s@ut}
% \begin{macro}{\protected@write@immediate}
% \begin{macro}{\immediateaddtocontents}
% \begin{macro}{\addtocontentsline}
% \begin{macro}{\my@readwrite@line}
% \begin{macro}{\my@docum@nt}
% \begin{macro}{\my@end@docum@nt}
% \begin{environment}{document}
% \begin{macro}{\my@sym@def}
% \begin{macro}{\my@sym@LANG@def}
% \begin{macro}{\my@s@l@ctl@ngu@g@}
% \begin{macro}{\selectlanguage}
% \begin{macro}{\my@ch@pt@r@}
% \begin{macro}{\@chapter}
% \begin{environment}{symbols}
%    \begin{macrocode}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}%%%%
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\RequirePackage{xargs}%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{acronym,suffix,xargs,xifthen,xspace}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\LoadClass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}[2007/10/19]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommandx\my@op@n[3][addprefix=\global,1=template,2=.txt,3=.tex]{%
  \newread\my@file%
  \immediate\openin\my@file=#1\myLANG#2%
  \newwrite\my@fil@%
  \immediate\openout\my@fil@=#1\myLANG#3%
}

\newcommandx\my@s@ut[0][addprefix=\global]{%
  \immediate\closein\my@file%
  \immediate\closeout\my@fil@%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Code borrowed from `multitoc.dtx' of CTAN /macros/latex/contrib/ms
%% Copyright (c) [1998..1999]  Martin Schr\"oder. All rights reserved.

\newcommand*{\protected@write@immediate}[3]{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\string
       \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}%
       \reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
   }

\newcommand*{\immediateaddtocontents}[2]{%
  \protected@write@immediate\@auxout
      {\let\label\@gobble \let\index\@gobble \let\glossary\@gobble}%
      {\string\@writefile{#1}{#2}}}

%%
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \immediateaddtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}

\newcommandx\my@readwrite@line[2][addprefix=\global\protect,1=-1,2=to]{%
  \catcode`\\=12\catcode`\{=12\catcode`\}=12\catcode`\$=12%
  \catcode`\#=12\catcode`\^=12\catcode`\_=12\catcode`\%=12%
  \let\my@var\endlinechar%
  \endlinechar=#1%
  \immediate\read\my@file#2\my@lin@%
  \endlinechar=\my@var%
  \catcode`\%=14\catcode`\_=8\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\#=6%
  \catcode`\$=3\catcode`\}=2\catcode`\{=1\catcode`\\=0%
  \protected@xdef\my@line{\my@lin@}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\my@line}{}}{}{%
  \protected@write@immediate\my@fil@{\relax}{\my@line\@backslashchar\@backslashchar}}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\let\my@docum@nt\document
\let\my@end@docum@nt\enddocument
\renewenvironmentx{document}[2][1=pre,2]{%
  \my@op@n%
  \my@docum@nt%%%%%
  \input{#1.tex}%
  \ifx\\#2\\\else\selectlanguage{#2}\fi%
  \ignorespaces%%%%%%%%%
}{\my@end@docum@nt%
  \ignorespacesafterend%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommandx\my@sym@def[1][addprefix=\global]{%
  \expandafter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \newcommandx\csname#1\endcsname[4][addprefix=\global,3,4]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{##3}%
    }{\ifthenelse{\isempty{##4}%
      }{\acro{##1}{{##2}}%%%%%%%%%
      }{\acro{##1}[{##2}]{{##4}}}%
    }{\ifthenelse{\isempty{##4}%
      }{\acro{##1}{{##2}\acroextra{{##3}}}%%%%%%%%
      }{\acro{##1}[{##2}]{{##4}\acroextra{{##3}}}%
    }}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname##1\endcsname{\acl{##1}\xspace{}}%%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname##1*\endcsname{\acs{##1}\xspace{}}%
  }%
}

\newcommandx\my@sym@LANG@def[2][addprefix=\global]{%
  \expandafter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \newcommandx\csname#1#2\endcsname[4][3,4]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{##3}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    }{\@nameuse{#1}{##1}{\@nameuse{#2}{##2}}[][##4]%
    }{\@nameuse{#1}{##1}{\@nameuse{#2}{##2}}%%%%%%%%
                        [\@nameuse{#2}{##3}][##4]%%%
    }%
  }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\let\my@s@l@ctl@ngu@g@\selectlanguage
\renewcommand\selectlanguage[1]{%%%%%%%%%%%
\my@s@l@ctl@ngu@g@{#1}\@nameuse{do\myLANG}}

\let\my@ch@pt@r@\@chapter
\renewcommandx\@chapter[3][1,2,3]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
    \GenericError{}{empty chapter name}{%%%
      stop}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      here.}}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \ifx\\#3\\\else\selectlanguage{#3}\fi%
  \my@ch@pt@r@[#1]{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\thechapter\nobreakspace#1}%
  \addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{\thechapter\nobreakspace#1}%
  \ifx\\#2\\\else\label{chp:#2}\fi%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironmentx{symbols}[1][1]{%
  \pagestyle{empty}%%%%%%%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%%%
  \chapter*{Symbols}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Symbols}%
  \begin{acronym}[{#1}]%
}{\end{acronym}%%%%%%%%%
  \clearpage%
}

%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{environment}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{environment}
```

This is `mwe.ins`.

```
\def\batchfile{mwe.ins}
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\generateFile{mwe.cls}{t}{\from{mwe.dtx}{class}}
```

This is `ltxdoc.cfg`.

```
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}
\AtEndOfPackage{%
\hyphenation{tocprelim semifinal draft}
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}%
\RequirePackage{hyperref}%
}
```

This is `mwe.tex`.

```
% -*- mode: latex; unibyte: nil; coding: utf-8 -*-

\documentclass{./mwe}

\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ș}{\c{s}}\newunicodechar{Ș}{\c{S}}
\newunicodechar{ț}{\c{t}}\newunicodechar{Ț}{\c{T}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\RO[1]{\foreignlanguage{romanian}{#1}\xspace{}}
\newcommand\doRO{\relax}
\xdef\myLANG{RO}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter

\my@sym@def{sym}
\@expandtwoargs\my@sym@LANG@def{sym}{\myLANG}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Minimal Working Example}
\author{acronym}

\begin{document}[preamble][romanian]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------%

\inputencoding{latin10}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{my@cnt}%
\setcounter{my@cnt}{0}%

\@whilenum\arabic{my@cnt}<24\do{%
  \my@readwrite@line%
  \stepcounter{my@cnt}%
}

\my@s@ut%

\makeatother

\noindent%
\input{templateRO}

\inputencoding{utf8}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter[Oscilații][osc][romanian]

\HZO~e formula pentru \HZO*.

\end{document}
```

This is `preamble.tex`.

```
% -*- mode: latex; unibyte: t; coding: utf-8 -*-

\maketitle

\begin{symbols}[WORD]

  \symRO{HZO}{Apă}[\hfill făcută din 3 elemente și 2 molecule][$H_2O$]

\end{symbols}

\tableofcontents
```

The sequence is: latex mwe.ins; pdftex -shell-escape mwe.tex #twice

The file `templateRO.txt` as specified here -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_alphabet#Unicode_and_HTML -- contains 8-bit letters with commas, not cedillas.

```
Thesis
Submitted in Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for
the Degree of Doctor of Philosophy
in Computer Science
to the Faculty of Engineering of the
University of Rome
by

Conducător științific
Referenți științifici

Ziua susținerii tezei

Acest document este în domeniul public.

Acknowledgements

Dedicație

Keywords

Lista de acronime
Lista de teoreme
Lista de demonstrații
```

thank s.

Comment: Don't mix encoding. It's better to convert the Latin-10 document into UTF-8.

Comment: @egreg: I have used `\inputencoding` without problems to include listings in ansi in an utf8-document. I do find this `\catcode` changes much more doubtful. What's their purpose?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Here the problem seems to be in what TeX writes out under the `latin10` regime. I don't even ask myself what those `\catcode` instruction are for.

Comment: @egreg `\acro` writes to the `aux`. But normally this shouldn't be a problem as it will expand non-ascii chars to LICR-commands (`\"a` etc.). But if the `\catcodes` are changed you get non-ascii-chars in the aux-file and together with the encoding changes things get messy.

Comment: You should not have to change the catcodes. inputenc should allow switching between catcodes without that. In fact by making characters catcode 12 you break inputenc's mechanisms entirely.

Comment: @egreg it will write in latin10 as the characters have been made catcode 12. If they were left as 13 the writing would be done using internal encoding-independent commands.

Comment: Your question after editing no longer has any code that may be run. Please make it a complete document using an easily available class such as article. As I can not run anything I can't help much other than note that your point 4 is wrong. There is no reason to change catcodes to change encoding. If you do you will break latex's encoding support entirely and the  kind of errors you show would be expected. Similarly don't use `\immediate\write` unless you carefully set `\protect` beforehand or simpler use `\@protected@write` (or if necessary an immediate version of that)

Comment: i will give it a try for monday.

Comment: The reedited MWE shows why i keep from commenting out `%\catcodeXYZ=ij` lines in `mwe.tex` and have `\protected@write` in `mwe.dtx` instead, or else i get an error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer & @egreg: the purpose of `\catcode`'s is a `\TeX`nique in-between the text template writer easy editing and `\LaTeX` input streams' tested impossibility (as contrary to `\XeTeX` and `\LuaTex` i heard) to handle `UTF-8` encoding. That is: 1) templates could have been unicode, yet because `UTF-8` is **not single-byte**, `\read`ing them and `\write`ing them as `UTF-8` [chars sequence *per* letter] to a `.tex` file to be `\input`ed next, cannot succeed; 2) have template writers specify **just** the `\cacode`'s list of letters they use, and let class do `\inputencoding` switching.

Comment: @sjbiaga: I (and also Enrico) knows quite well what `\catcode` does, how `inputenc` works (with 8bit encodings and with utf8) and how non-ascii-chars are written to file by default. But with your `\catcode` command you are treading on the toes of `inputenc`. Also it is dangerous to write non-ascii to files if more than one encoding is involved: Files can be written and readed while different encodings are "active". It is much better to let latex replace the chars by the LICR-commands (`\u{a}`). They will work reliably. Take a step back and rethink what you are doing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: "Take a step back [...] doing." Thanks for your answer; i see the danger, why the `\inputencoding` command anyway? i am "worried". i recognize i can't figure it out: 1) switching to `utf-8` is **next after** `\input` *volatile* `.tex` in the same encoding, and then continues from "preamble"; 2) it just won't work without the `\catcode`'s trick, **i tried, of course**, in the original class, i just do `\newcommand\my@set@cat[2]{}%\catcode#1=#2}`. Forget about `acronym` and `.aux`: why is the rest of the `\LaTeX` source files' (and not the "volatile" template) parsing affected?

Comment: on second level, 3) it looks like avoiding "the LICR commands" is what i'm trying to do; so 4) in the same `\inputencoding` "cycle" you mean `\catcodeXYZ=ij` is forbidden?

Comment: 5) "much better to let latex replace the chars by the LICR-commands (\u{a})": i would let happily **to replace**, but 6) **the error is** these LICR-commands must be required straight from what is typeset...

Comment: there are two "alternatives", both resulting in error. if i chose yours, forgetting `\catcodes`, this would be a correct step back, and i would retake from there :) but it's this new error `! Argument of \stepcounter has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.53 }
      ^^M`
i don't get the interplay between `\immediate\read` and `\protect` on `\write`, or `\protected@write`: how would these two should be correctly used in the MWE?

Comment: ok, i borrowed "`\protect@writed@immediate`" code from `multitoc` and got it work. Thank you for guidance.

Comment: @sjbiaga And now the question is?

Comment: @egreg Yes, it seems i'm back where i started; except i discovered `acronym` needed to redefine `\protected@write` too, so it translates to `\protected@write@immediate`. However, the `\protected@write` is used also in `\addtocontents` and `\@wrindex` and both `\chapter` and `\index` commands yield the same error w.r.t. `utf8` characters `0218`, `0219`, `021A`, `021B`. With `acronym` is now clearly the issue with `\protected@write`, is it the same for `\@wrindex` and `\addtocontents` from `latex.ltx`? (Note it is not with the MWE above, but with my real class and sources.)

Comment: ) [15] [16] (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def)
Capitolul 2.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   :
l.104 \chapter[Oscilații][osc][romanian]                   :
l.104 \chapter[Oscilații][osc][romanian]
                                         
? x
`\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{2}Oscila\c {t}ii}{\thepage }}`

i press ENTER the first time on the error, and `@writefile` is from `.aux`.

Comment: i outruled the errors by surrounding `\inputencoding{latin10}` related code inside `\begingroup` -_- `\endgroup` pairs; the question is now: how do i make `\newcommand`'s available outside? if you're still willing to answer... thank s.

Comment: that is, between succesive `\begingroup` -_- `\endgroup` pairs, so not quite "outside" (since outside is `utf-8`, and the `\newcommand`'s have `latin10` LICR-content).

Answer (score 2):

The main file should not have the catcode changes they disable `inputenc`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin10,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{acronym}

\newunicodechar{ș}{\c{s}}\newunicodechar{Ș}{\c{S}}
\newunicodechar{ț}{\c{t}}\newunicodechar{Ț}{\c{T}}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{romanian}

\inputencoding{latin10}


\input{symbols}



\inputencoding{utf8}

\chapter{Oscilații}

\end{document}
```

You will need to delete the `.aux` file so latex will then write a correct one that should look like this:

```
\relax 
\reset@newl@bel
\select@language{romanian}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{romanian}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{romanian}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{romanian}}
\select@language{romanian}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{romanian}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{romanian}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{romanian}}
\newacro{Ap\u a}[\AC@hyperlink{Ap\u a}{Ap\u a}]{f\u acut\u a din 3 elemente \tex
tcommabelow si 2 molecule}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Oscila\c {t}ii}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
```

Note the aux file characters are never written as characters but using latex commands so they can be read back even if the file is using a different encoding at that point.

Comment: oops, i hurried and put things in different order. but, i hope you continue this question because this is exactly what i am doing, just as in `.aux`. so you understand: i take `\immediate\read` lines from plain-text templates, transform then and then format or do `\immediate\write`s (\newcommand) in a la `.aux` style, which i then `\input` back. But i also mix template with source, so i reached a `\TeX`nique for this. I will edit the question, although the MWE will work, and explain where it comes from.

Comment: If you are using `\immediate\write\@auxout` rather than `\protected@write` then you are probably not enablung LaTeX's protect mechanism and so will get "fragile command in moving argument" errors.

Comment: Why should i delete the `.aux` file? You mean the `.aux` file has `\newacro` with `UTF-8` encoded args, and it is read back in a moment when `\inputencoding{latin10}` is active? How can i then intervene or anticipate?

Comment: You only need to delete the aux file once, after you have fixed the main file not to have the catcode changes. Because you disabled inputenc that way the aux file is corrupt and even if you fix the main file the old aux file is read in at the start of the document and will generate errors. So fix the main file, delete the aux (and toc and any other files written previously) then re-run and it should be OK.

Comment: I cannot fix the main file anymore. I reedited the MWE. If you please, comment out `%\catcodeXYZ=ij` lines in `mwe.tex` and have `\protected@write` in `mwe.dtx` instead: here, i do these the error i get, cannot fix it. (i delete `.*` files except `\LaTeX` source.)

Comment: a `\makeatletter` just after `\my@readwrite@line` initially solved the error, but was not necessary once i used `\protected@writed@immediate`.

Comment: Sorry I tried, I can offer no further help. Your "MWE" is far from minimal and I have no idea how to run it. the .ins extracts but your instructions say `pdftex -shell-escape mwe.tex1 but that generates errors as it is latex not plain tex and if I run pdflatex mwe it stops asking for input `\my@lin@=` and I have no idea what you expect the user to do at that point. The answer I gave originally shows there is no problem with the packages mentioned in the heading you seem to be having errors with your own low level file writing but you have given no indication of what you are trying to write.

Comment: the `\my@lin@=` is caused by unbalance between counter limit and lines' count in the `.txt` template. the MWE just copies lines identically. but now it works, i followed your hints about `\protected@write` and i found  `multitoc.dtx` has implemented. thank s. (i mention about "`LaTeX`'s protect mechanism" in the class doc.)